# Send Base64 with JSONObject to server(ANDROID)

Tags: android, json, base64

I think I'm getting a weird encoding error when I encode an image to base 64 and try to send it through a JSON.

I'm encoding the photo that starts as a Bitmap like this:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the I send the "encoded" String on the json

```
 JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

        postDataParams.put(ArchivoTexto, encoded);
```

now the problem that I see is that when I send the JSON the encoded string that the console says its sending something that looks like this:

```
\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wB
```

but if I copy to the clipboard the "encoded" String it looks like this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wB
```

the backslashes disappear, and if I use a website to decode the string that comes from the clipboard it successfully decodes the image, but when I send the string to a server through the JSON it just looks broken, so I suspect that the backslashes are making it break.

My question is should I look for a way to remove the backslashes before sending the string on a JSON or is the server's fault for not being able to interpret the string correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your PHP file

1. Make a Json String from posted data (base64), and remove "\n" character (to avoid that character)
2. Decode that JSON String to remove that JSON Character
3. Get the decoded string

This is work for me

```
$img_base64 = $_POST['ArchivoTexto'];
$sdata = '{"val" : "'.sub_str("\n","",$img_base64).'"}';

$ddata = json_decode($sdata);

$jdata = $ddata->val;//$jdata contain the clear base64 String
```

Answer (score 1):

conver bitmap to base64 String by this

```
public static String getBase64Image(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

and call this way and replace \n to ""

```
String Base64Photo = getBase64Image(decodeFile(bitmap)).replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are sending the encoded String as by putting it into JSONObject don't do that, it might be the reason of those backslashes.**

**I would recommend using Volley for sending image to Server.**

`private void uploadImage() {`

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Do something with response
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("image",imageToString(mBitmap)); //passing bitmap for converting into String
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
    mRequestQueue.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);  //mRequestQueue is from Volley
}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

}
```

Comment: tnx for answer.
but i want send some picture that save encodingStream of them to ArrayList
now i want send all image to server in one request.
i think JSONObject the best way for do it.